# SUM all row based on selected name First Column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I want to SUM all row column based on the selected name in the first column, What I've tried is the formula below,but it return me Total = 3 it just return the first value, the result should `5` since I selected named `Edwin` need help

```
=SUMIF(A2:A4,"*Edwin*",B2:D4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:D5)*(A3:A5=B8))
```

For ***Microsoft-365*** you can use `FILTER()`.

```
=SUM(FILTER(B3:D5,A3:A5=B8))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have idea when there's string or text included in the number eg. Macky   |2 |2 rejected| 2 not rejected  currently the formula not working to `SUM` since there's string included, need help

Comment: Incredible and versatile `SUMPRODUCT()` Function, very nice trick with `FILTER()` Function Dada

Comment: I will update formula when get free.